# Can you use Visual Studios instead of Web Matrix for orchard 1.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, orchardcms

I installed orchard through the MS web platform installer. It listed web matrix as a dependency and once finished installing it loaded up web matrix.

I am wondering if I can just use VS 2010 instead or does orchard have some setting set for web matrix or something that would require me to do some configuration in VS 2010(ie some iis stuff)?

Thanks

P.S

I tried going to the path where the orchard files are located(that was listed in web matrix) and load up the cs project file into Vs but it seems to be missing folders such as the "Themes" folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](http://orchardproject.net/docs/Creating-a-module-with-a-simple-text-editor.ashx) from the Orchard Documentation shows that you can create a module using just a text editor.  I would think that using Visual Studio would also be doable, though I can't find an explicit example using VS 2010.

### Edit

The documentation has full instructions to [enlist in the source code and use Visual Studio 2010 to build Orchard](http://orchardproject.net/docs/Setting-up-a-source-enlistment.ashx).

Comment: Can you run it without setting up iis? Like you can run mvc projects and webform projects through the built in casinii in VS?

Comment: You don't need IIS at all, I've been running on cassini, iis and iis express as well.

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can use VS2010 only if you like, and that's the way I prefer it myself, but you should use the full source for Orchard. Go to the [Download](http://orchardproject.net/download) page download the full source code.

After that you got many good tutorials on the [Documentation](http://docs.orchardproject.net/) page.

Good luck!

Comment: why should I use the full source? None of the tutorials that I seen so far mention to use the full source one.

Comment: I understand your question, but it's recommended by many in the forums, especially if you end up creating your own themes and want to start overriding views. You may even want to create your own widget or module later on and you will get into small troubles unless you work with the full source code, trust me - been there :/